# Read JWT token from different HTTP header in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

In an ASP.NET Core API project, I need to validate another JWT Bearer token located in header different than the Authorization header. For example, imagine sending a GET request to get products to `/api/products` with a Bearer token in a header named `AccessToken`.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://localhost/api/products' \
--header 'AccessToken: <bearer_token>'
```

I'm referencing the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/) package and setting authentication in the API project like this:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => Configuration.Bind("JwtSettings", options));
```

However, I cannot find anything regarding a header name inside the [JwtBearerOptions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.jwtbeareroptions?view=aspnetcore-1.1).

**How can I configure the JWT authentication to read the JWT from a header named "AccessToken"?**
Is it even possible using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer package?

Comment: Per the source: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8b30d862de6c9146f466061d51aa3f1414ee2337/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L53, this middleware will ONLY look at the auth header. If you want to do something else, you'll need to write that middleware yourself.

Comment: You have to write a custom middleware inside your startup.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solutions seems to be to use the [JwtBearerEvents class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents?view=aspnetcore-5.0). In it, there's a delegate [property named OnMessageReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents.onmessagereceived?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_JwtBearer_JwtBearerEvents_OnMessageReceived)  that it's "invoked when a protocol message is first received". The delegate will pass a object of type of [MessageReceivedContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.messagereceivedcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0), where it has a property named Token that [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.messagereceivedcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0) **"This will give the application an opportunity to retrieve a token from an alternative location"**.

Create a class that inherits from JwtBearerEvents and in the OnMessageReceived event set the token in the context object to the value from the header "AccessToken".

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Singleton class handler of events related to JWT authentication
/// </summary>
public class AuthEventsHandler : JwtBearerEvents
{
    private const string BearerPrefix = "Bearer ";

    private AuthEventsHandler() => OnMessageReceived = MessageReceivedHandler;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets single available instance of <see cref="AuthEventsHandler"/>
    /// </summary>
    public static AuthEventsHandler Instance { get; } = new AuthEventsHandler();

    private Task MessageReceivedHandler(MessageReceivedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("AccessToken", out StringValues headerValue))
        {
            string token = headerValue;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) && token.StartsWith(BearerPrefix))
            {
                token = token.Substring(BearerPrefix.Length);
            }

            context.Token = token;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Finally, add the events class to the JWT authentication at the Startup class.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => 
{
    Configuration.Bind("JwtSettings", options);
    options.Events = AuthEventsHandler.Instance;
});
```

Comment: This works, however if the token isn't found, the handler will fallback to checking the normal Authorization header. This means the token can be sent in either header which may not be wanted. To prevent that from happening, you need to call `context.NoResult()` if the token isn't found. The handler will return early if it sees the result has been set, rather than continuing normal processing.

Comment: mate you're a legend - there are no resources about on how to use the JwtBearerEvents at all - this helped me a ton. I post the token as a form content and this allows me to use that instead of the auth header.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 you’re right, the code is missing a section to avoid falling back on the default of using the Authorize header. I completely missed it, good catch!

Comment: Wish I could give you massive kudos for this.  Awesome find and explanation!

Comment: Very valuable answer. One thing I'd mention is use ignore case while checking if it starts with "Bearer": `token.StartsWith(BearerPrefix, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` My tokens would sometimes start with "Bearer ..." and the other times with "bearer ..."